# Get the "Share" tab to show "Share As" after importing MXD using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I have imported an MXD into ArcGIS Pro, now I want to upload it to ESRI Online.  I am signed into ESRI Online in ArcGIS Pro.  When I click on the tab for the imported MXD my "Share" tab shows this:

[image]

However if I add a new blank map to the project and select its tab I get what I am after:
[image]

So I am wondering how to get the "Share As" options to share as a web map when I am working with the imported MXD and not the blank map.

Comment: Looks like you have no layers in your map to share? All you are showing is the basemap and you can't upload those as they already exist in AGOL.

Comment: @Hornbydd the map with only the basemap isn't the issue (2nd screenshot), the question asks about the "map" in the 1st screenshot.  Which isn't a map, it's a layout.

Comment: @forestGIS you're comparing two different things. 1st screenshot shows a layout, 2nd shows a map.  Go to your catalog pane and find the map that is used in the layouts map frame (assuming that got imported as well from the MXD), open the map itself and you should get the same Share tab.